# How to make an Icon overlay over an image

Tags: flutter, frontend, flutter-layout

I'm new to flutter and not that experienced when it comes to programming in general. So I'm trying to do something like this

[image]

But I just can't seem to do it, I tried align properties, padding to make it move left and right, I also tried stacks but I don't have any idea how to do it.

This is my code for the image

```
Widget buildImage() {
return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10, top: 20),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 130,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: new DecorationImage(
            image: new AssetImage(
              "assets/images/profile-image.jpeg",
            ),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.white,
            width: 5.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ));
 }
```

This is my current progress

[image]

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () => {},
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.grey[200],
                child: Icon(Icons.person),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 60,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.grey[200]),
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with the [Stack widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) check the docs it has a video explaining it really well.

It lets you positions its children relative to the edges of its box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack to place widget over widget. Here is the working example

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: new DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage(
                  "assets/images/profile-image.jpeg",
                ),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.white,
                width: 5.0,
              )),
          height: 100,
          width: 130,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Container(
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.blue),
            child: Center(
              child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```